# making listview from multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, listview

I need to make a listview from two (or more) tables (i am using sql server).
My project is about apartments rental.

i have a table of Owner:

```
[OwnerID]     INT        IDENTITY (1, 1)    NOT NULL,
[Name]        NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Username]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Password]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Phone]       NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Mail]        NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Description] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Image]       IMAGE         NULL,
```

And i have a table of Apartment:

```
[ApartmentID]     INT           NOT NULL,
[Address]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[OwnerID]         INT           NULL,
[AgentID]         INT           NULL,
[apartmentTypeID] INT           NOT NULL,
[Floor]           INT           NOT NULL,
[Rooms]           INT           NOT NULL,
[AgencyFees]      INT           NULL,
[Immediately]     INT           NOT NULL,
[DateOfEntrance]  DATETIME      NULL,
[Price]           INT           NOT NULL,
[Description]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Image]           IMAGE         NULL,
[CityID]          INT           NOT NULL,
```

I want to show the data of the table Apartment in a **listview**, but instead of the field "ownerID", i want to show the ownerName from the Owner table. I understand i need to use a linq here somehow...

If someone can show me how to do this, i will appreciate it :-)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider JOINing these two tables, like check this query,

```
SELECT 
t1.[ApartmentID],
t1.[Address],
t2.[Name],
t1.[AgentID],
t1.[apartmentTypeID],
t1.[Floor],
t1.[Rooms],
t1.[AgencyFees],
t1.[Immediately],
t1.[DateOfEntrance],
t1.[Price],
t1.[Description],
t1.[Image],
t1.[CityID]
FROM
Apartment AS t1 INNER JOIN Owner AS t2
ON t1.[OwnerID]=t2.[OwnerID];
```

Here is LINQ,

```
var q = (from t1 in Apartment join t2 in Owner on t1.OwnerID equals t2.OwnerID
 select new { 
    t1.ApartmentID,
    t1.Address,
    t2.Name,
    t1.AgentID,
    t1.apartmentTypeID,
    t1.Floor,
    t1.Rooms,
    t1.AgencyFees,
    t1.Immediately,
    t1.DateOfEntrance,
    t1.Price,
    t1.Description,
    t1.Image,
    t1.CityID
 }).ToList();
```

Hope it helps, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have now 2 more questions:

1. How can i put this in list view?
When i did a listview from only one table, i used object data source...
2. I am using the layers model: DAL, BLBackend, BLFrontend, PL.
When i wanted to use only the Apartment table, i did a linq in BLBackend:

            DataLayer dal = new DataLayer();
            var ls = from a in dal.ReadApartments() 
                     where (a.City.CityID == CityID || CityID == -1).....
select a;

            List<Apartment> list = ls.ToList<Apartment>();
            return list;

How am i suppose to do this now?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!
I did this inside a function. What type of list should I return (now that this is from two tables)?

Comment: List of `Apartment`, but your `Apartment` class must have a string property to hold OwnerName.